# How can I configure the jsdom instance used by jest?

Tags: jestjs, jsdom, systemjs

I've come up against this issue [Invalid URL is thrown when requiring systemjs in jest test cases](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/840)

One of the last comments suggests

"manipulate the jsdom instance to have a valid location / baseURI by setting the referrer config in jsdom."

I'm wondering is there way for me to do that? Can I access the `jsdom` instance somehow from the `jest` object?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue when using a project requiring a url (location.href). You can configure jest with a testURL in your configuration.

Here is what you might put in your package.json (if that is how you configure jest).

```
"jest": {
    ...other config,
    "testURL": "http://localhost:8080/Dashboard/index.html"
}
```

[testURL Doc](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#testurl-string)

If you need more specific changes to jsdom you can install jsdom yourself and import and configure it separately from jest. Here is an example:

test.js

```
'use strict';
import setup from './setup';
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Reportlet from '../components/Reportlet.jsx';

it('Reportlet Renders', () => {
    ...some test stuff
});
```

setup.js

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
const DEFAULT_HTML = '<html><body></body></html>';

// Define some variables to make it look like we're a browser
// First, use JSDOM's fake DOM as the document
global.document = jsdom.jsdom(DEFAULT_HTML);

// Set up a mock window
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.window.location = "https://www.bobsaget.com/"
// ...Do extra loading of things like localStorage that are not supported by jsdom
```

Comment: Note that `testURL` was removed in Jest 28, it can now be set via `testEnvironmentOptions.url` in `jest.config.js` instead (see https://github.com/jestjs/jest/pull/10797).

Answer (score 2):

I just went down this road and found out that as of Jest 21.2.1, the official way is to fork your own JSDom environment.

This is a bit painful to set up but allows in-depth customization.

References:

- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2484#issuecomment-270174381
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2460#issuecomment-324630534

Sample environment: https://github.com/mes/jest-environment-jsdom-external-scripts

Comment: This is hard mode, for sure. But I don't see any other alternatives documented on the web, and Jest's official position seems to be "no."

Answer (score 0):

jsdom is the default environment that the latest version of Jest uses, so you can simply manipulate the global variables such as `window`, `document` or `location`.

Comment: From jsdom v11, `window.location` object become not configurable, and thus can not be modified with `Object.defineProperty()` anymore.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using `jsdom` (ver 11.12.0) without `jest` (e.g. with `ava + enzyme`)
then you can set url in jsdom config file

File `src/test/jsdom-config.js`

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom') // eslint-disable-line
const { JSDOM } = jsdom

const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><head/><body></body>', {
  url: 'http://localhost/',
  referrer: 'https://example.com/',
  contentType: 'text/html',
  userAgent: 'Mellblomenator/9000',
  includeNodeLocations: true,
  storageQuota: 10000000,
})
global.window = dom.window
global.document = window.document
global.navigator = window.navigator
```

AVA settings in `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": ...
  ...
  "ava": {
    "babel": "inherit",
    "files": [
      "src/**/*.test.js"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
    "require": [
      "babel-register",
      "ignore-styles",
      "./src/test/jsdom-setup.js",
      "./src/test/enzyme-setup.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: p.s. I've just found this question while trying to solve my non-jest problem